# What is a Flamenco Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%20is%20%22%20%22Word%22%20-missing%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

---

If a word satisfies a certain property, it is called a Flamenco Word™. Find out what the rule is given the following examples.

| Flamenco Words™ | non-Flamenco Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| Flamenco | Dancing |
| Iambic | Pentameter |
| Lemon | Zest |
| Preset | Format |
| Effigy | Statue |
| Mentor | Teacher |
| Kilt | Skirt |
| True | False |
| Leaf | Petal |
| Plum | Peach |

And a CSV Version:

```
FLAMENCO, DANCING
IAMBIC, PENTAMETER
LEMON, ZEST
PRESET, FORMAT
EFFIGY, STATUE
MENTOR, TEACHER
KILT, SKIRT
TRUE, FALSE
LEAF, PETAL
PLUM, PEACH
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A Flamenco word is one which satisfies the following rule

> Either the letters in odd-numbered positions or those in even-numbered positions are alphabetically adjacent and ascending.

Examples

> FLAMENCO -> _L_M_N_O
>  IAMBIC -> _A_B_C
>  EFFIGY -> E_F_G_
>  TRUE -> T_U_
>  LEMON -> L_M_N
>  PRESET -> _R_S_T

Answer (score 14):

Too long for a comment. Following the logic of the answer given by @hexomino, I wrote a short script to find all flamenco words:

> Using a word list of ~40k English words, I found 293 flamenco words in total (ignoring 2-letter words or 3-letter words that only use the center letter). Most of the words are of length 3 (21 words), 4 (125 words), and 5 (122 words). The words of length 6 and longer are as follows.
>  **Length 6:** cadger, codger, cudgel, effigy, iambic, lament, lamina, lemony, manioc, mentor, minion, minnow, preset (13 words).
>  **Length 7:** aliment, alimony, alumina, clement, element, fatback, flaming, leafage, payback, sawbuck (10 words).
>  **Length 8:** flamenco, flamingo (2 words), tying for the title of longest flamenco word.

> If we define a Doubly Flamenco Word to be one for which both the odd- and even-positioned letters are in ascending alphabetical order, the only Double Flamenco Word found was "lamb" ( `_A_B` and `L_M_` )